# HTML How to change color background in body using nodes

Tags: html, nodes

I have an exercice asking me to change the color of a letter and the color of the background when clicking on a piece of text. 
The changing of the text works, but I cannot get the function to change the background color. Any help?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title page</title>
<style>
.red { color : #FF0000 }
.green { color : #00FF00 }
.blue { color : #00F0F0 }
.big { font-size: xx-large }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function f(){
  node=document.getElementById('i1');
  node.childNodes[3].className='green';
  //nodeBdy=document.getElementById('bdy'); This is probably wrong
  //nodeBdy.childNodes[2].className='blue' This is probably wrong
}
</script>
</head>
<body id='bdy' class='big' bgcolor="">
<h5>Changing style (class)</h5>
<p id='i1'>This is <em> special </em> <span class='red'>text</span>.</p>
<p onclick='f();'>Click to change the colour of text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to change? Because you can just add the `background-color: whatever:` to the class-assignments you already have?

Comment: are you allowed to use Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to change the background color and the text when you click. Use: background-color instead of color. Color is for changing the text color not the background.

```js
function f(){
  document.getElementById('text').className = 'green';
  document.getElementById('bdy').className = 'blue';
}
```

```css
.red { color : #FF0000 }
.green { color : #00FF00 }
.blue { background-color : #00F0F0 }
.big { font-size: xx-large }
```

```html
<body id='bdy' class='big' bgcolor="">
<h5>Changing style (class)</h5>
<p id='i1'>This is <em> special </em> <span id="text" class='red'>text</span>.</p>
<p onclick='f();'>Click to change the colour of text</p>
</body>
```

but this is a really silly way of doing this...
let me know if u want any tips on how to do this better :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the background-color property to it, for example:

```
.red { color : #FF0000; background-color: #CCFFCC }
.green { color : #00FF00; background-color: #CC66FF }
.blue { color : #00F0F0; background-color: #FFFF99 }
```

[Here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001391.htm) is another link you may find helpful, it covers both HTML and HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```js
function f() {
  node = document.getElementById('i1');
  if (node.childNodes[3].className == 'red')
    node.childNodes[3].className = 'green';
  else
    node.childNodes[3].className = 'red';
  
  var color = document.getElementById("bdy").style.background;
  if (color == "red")
    document.getElementById("bdy").style.background = "white";
  else
    document.getElementById("bdy").style.background = "red";
}
```

```css
#bdy{
    background-color: white;
}
.red {
  color: #FF0000;
}
.green {
  color: #00FF00;
}
.blue {
  color: #00F0F0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title page</title>
</head>

<body id='bdy' class='big' bgcolor="">
  <h5>Changing style (class)</h5>
  <p id='i1'>This is <em> special </em>  <span class='red'>text</span>.</p>
  <a onclick='f();'>Click to change the colour of text</a>
</body>

</html>
```